# What was and who were Bath-Sheva's or Bath-Shua's Name and Children with David and Uriah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, names, king-david, book-of-chronicles

What was and who were Bath-Sheva's or Bath-Shua's Name and Children with David and Uriah?

> Divrei Hayamim I - I Chronicles - Chapter 3:5 And these were born to
> him in Jerusalem: Shimea, and Shobab, and Nathan, and Solomon-four, to
> Bath Shua the daughter of Ammiel.

https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16523/showrashi/true

Is the first-born son listed here the first child that died?
Do we know if Bath-Sheva had any children with her prior spouse, Uriah?
Did Uriah call her "Bath-Shua"; otherwise, why is Bath-Sheva's name interchangeable with Bath-Shua?

Answer (score 2):

The children are not listed in their correct order and the child that died is not mentioned.

The [Metzudas Dovid](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.5?lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_David_on_I_Chronicles.3.5.1&lang2=bi) points this out:

> שמעא. לא מנאם כסדר תולדותם כי שלמה היה הראשון
>
> Shimea - They are not listed in order of their birth, as Solomon was the first

[Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.3.5?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_I_Chronicles.3.5.2&lang2=bi) builds on this as also points out the interchangeable nature of her name. He says as follows:

> She is Bas Shua the daughter of Eliam, and there are those who read it Bas Sheva, and there are those (that read it) Bas Shua because they are related. And similarly Amiel (עמיאל) and Eliam (אליעם) - whereby they switch the letters around.
>
> And they don't list the four sons in their birth order, as Solomon (Shlomo) was the oldest since he was the first son of Bas Sheva from David, after the death of the child. And like it writes; "And David consoled Bas Sheva his wife. And he came to her, and she bore a son and called his name Solomon."...

Comment: Thanks, and did the rabbis of old mention any previous child that Bath-Sheva had with Uriah, her former spouse?

Comment: I don't know - I haven't seen any mention of any yet...